# AWS Cloudwatch - List Custom Metrics

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to figure out how to simply view all of our custom metrics in CloudWatch.

AWS Console is far from helpful, or at least it's not well signposted. I want to try and relate our CloudWatch bill to actual metrics we have to try and determine where I can make some cuts.

For Example:
Our Bill shows 1,600 Metrics charged at $0.30 a piece per month, but I see over 17,000 `custom namespaces` in the metrics list within the CloudWatch console.

Does anyone know how I can best find this information, or have a nice handy CLI command to view all custom metrics for a region?

I can see the `custom namespaces` section in cloud watch, but these don't really marry up to the billing page as such. By about a 10 fold.

Thank you.

**UPDATE**:
I think I may have identified why there is a discrepancy between the billing and the list of metrics:

1. We have namespace builds, each creating metrics and being destroyed sometimes within hours.
2. These metrics which were created linger for 15 days according to the AWS FAQ on CloudWatch Metrics.
3. The overall monthly `metrics` seemingly is a figure of what it is due to the concurrency of metrics over the month.

However, this still doesn't make the billing breakdown any easier to understand when you're trying to highlight possible outliers in costs.

Comment: `I want to try and relate our CloudWatch bill to actual metrics we have to try and determine where I can make some cuts.` can you clarify upon this

Comment: @JatinMehrotra I have updated the post. Hopefully that adds more clarity. Thanks.